# How to save a users progress in a Quiz game

Tags: ios, swift

I am wondering how I should save the users progress in my quiz game. Every time the user closes the app it resets. Here's my code:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds

class ViewController: UIViewController, GADBannerViewDelegate {
    //Place your instance variables here
    let allQuestions = QuestionBank()
    var pickedAnswer : Bool = false
    var questionNumber : Int = 0
    var score : Int = 0

    let googleAdTestID: String = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"

    @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var bannerView: GADBannerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var progressLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print("Google Mobile Ads SDK version: " + GADRequest.sdkVersion() )

        bannerView.adUnitID = googleAdTestID
        bannerView.rootViewController = self
        bannerView.load(GADRequest())

        nextQuestion()
    }

    @IBAction func skipButton(_ sender: Any) {
        skip()
    }

    func skip() {
        if score <= 4 {
        }
        else if score >= 5 {
            questionNumber = questionNumber + 1
            nextQuestion()
            score = score - 5
            scoreLabel.text = "Coins: \(score)"
        }
    }

    @IBAction func answerPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        if sender.tag == 1 {
            pickedAnswer = true
        }
        else if sender.tag == 2 {
            pickedAnswer = false
        }

        checkAnswer()
        questionNumber = questionNumber + 1
        nextQuestion()
    }

    func updateUI() {
        scoreLabel.text = "Coins: \(score)"
        progressLabel.text = "Question Number: \(questionNumber + 1)"
    }

    func nextQuestion() {
        if questionNumber <= 37 {
            questionLabel.text = allQuestions.list[questionNumber].questionText

            updateUI()
        }
        else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Awesome", message: "You have finished all the questions!! Do you want to start over?", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let restartAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Restart", style: .default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) in
                self.startOver()
            })
            alert.addAction(restartAction)
            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func checkAnswer() {
        let correctAnswer = allQuestions.list[questionNumber].answer

        if correctAnswer == pickedAnswer {
            print("Correct!")
            ProgressHUD.showSuccess("Correct!!")
            // varible += 1 same as varible = varible + 1
            score += 1
        }
        else {
            print("wrong!")
            ProgressHUD.showError("Wrong!!")
        }
    }

    func startOver() {
        questionNumber = 0
        nextQuestion()
        score = 0
        scoreLabel.text = "Score: 0"
    }
}
```

Comment: You can save it to cache. But, it won't be reset when user exit the app.. By the way, why you need to save it in the first place when it will be reset at closing the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save

```
// save necessory information using UserDefaults
// Add this code at your business logic
let database = UserDefaults.standard
let questionNumber = 2
database.set(questionNumber, forKey: "LAST_ANSWERED_QUESTION_NUMBER")
let score = 23
database.set(score, forKey: "QUIZ_SCORE")
let sync = database.synchronize()
if sync{
    print("userdefaults - sync done")
}else{
    print("userdefaults - failed to sync")
}
```

Fetch

```
//access stored values from UserDefaults
// Add this code at your business logic
let database = UserDefaults.standard
if let lastAnswredQuestion = database.value(forKey: "LAST_ANSWERED_QUESTION_NUMBER") as? Int{
    print("LAST_ANSWERED_QUESTION_NUMBER \(lastAnswredQuestion)")
}

if let scored = database.value(forKey: "QUIZ_SCORE") as? Int{
    print("QUIZ_SCORE \(scored)")
}
```

**NOTE:** The data will be stored until the app is installed, if the user deletes the app then whole data will vanish from UserDefaults.